# ipython notebook # find and replace has only replace "all" option

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

How to selectively replace some words in a single cell e.g. there are 7 variables named 'foo', and replace 3 of them by 'moo'.
The ipython notebook gives only option of replace all.

### Update

The version 6.1.1 of the notebook server does not all address this issue. However, I have shifted to Jupyter Lab 2.1.5, which allows selective replacement.

Comment: anyone have an update to this? this is a key missing feature.. we want to replace next and click next and son on... and stop or skip the next replace, etc. (not to replace all).

Comment: @ihightower would you open an issue on https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if it is not possible as of today.

Here's what one of the contributers says on the subject:

> I am opposed to trying implement that in our current UI - it doesn't
>   have the needed abstractions to do that well. In the new
>   JupyterLab/Workbench it will be quite easy to build a find/replace UI
>   in a separate panel that allows us to toggle the individual
>   replacements while still showing the notebook (in a non-model way).

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/558#issuecomment-164180866

Comment: Jupyter lab now has addressed this issue. After Ctrl + f, replace is available as an additional option.